# How can I skip queue messages and display action happend message in magento2.3?

Tags: products-management, magento2.3.2, message-queue

I am doing bulk update attribute from admin side in magento2.

I am not getting message of 'attribute has been updated' something like as.

I am getting below message which is attached in screen shot .

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 2.3 queues were added for product mass updates. You would need to run the consumer for `product_action_attribute.update` for it to process the updates.

In your case it would be
`bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update`, you could have multiple consumers running at the same time, but I guess one will do.

Comment: Ferraz can i skip these stuff and just show "product attribute has been updated " some thing like that message ?

Comment: can u answer this question? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301545/bulk-product-attribute-update-fails-in-the-magento-2-back-end

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint. I am experiencing the same issue. Is it so, that after each bulk update, we now need to run `bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update`via Composer in order to make changes visible?

Comment: Yes...Can you answer this one? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/301545/bulk-product-attribute-update-fails-in-the-magento-2-back-end