# Bulk product attribute update fails in the magento 2 back end

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.2, bulk-products-update, bulk-actions

When uploading the attributes for multiple products it fails each time. Kindly help me to solve this problem. My Magento version is 2.3.2

[image]

Comment: Make your cron job is properly running in live server. If not then please set cron job. it

Comment: cron job is already running.

Comment: It correctly showing Ran jobs by schedule.

Comment: please check all cron job log file

Comment: Can u answer this one? -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302106/sub-categories-are-not-showing-for-the-category-in-the-backend-magento-2

Comment: When you fixed it, please post the answer...

Comment: @KowsiganAtsayam are you able to solve this?